# Why are loop variables not being comprehended in this basic bash for loop?

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ bash -c "for VAR in {0..9}; do echo $VAR; done;
```

And a shell script containing exactly what's in the quotes behaves as expected.

The result is 10 blank lines - no matter which way I mildly edit this line (i.e. `/bin/bash` or `sh` instead of `bash`, or using `${VAR}`, `"$VAR"`, `"${VAR}"`, or a different variable name), and I get the same result outputting to a file.

If I use a variable name that I've set previously with just
`$ VAR=1`, this will output 1, 10 times.

Both `.bash` & `.bash_profile` look completely normal for my user. This is driving me insane, but did I miss something very obvious here?

Comment: replace the double quotes with single quotes. -c invokes a subshell or a it spawns a new shell afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what's happening by turning on debugging with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "for VAR in {0..9}; do echo $VAR; done;"
+ bash -c 'for VAR in {0..9}; do echo ; done;'
```

So, the double quotes around your `-c` expression are allowing the interactive parent shell to expand `$VAR` (to the empty string). It will work as you expect if you use single quotes:

```
bash -c 'for VAR in {0..9}; do echo $VAR; done;'
```

or escape the `$`:

```
bash -c "for VAR in {0..9}; do echo \$VAR; done;"
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've thought to use `set -x`, makes the issue pretty clear

Comment: @andersonm you're welcome - also notice that the brace expansion `{0-9}` is *not* expanded inside double quotes - that catches people out sometimes as well